# How do I limit a number of workers running in parallel in WorkManager?

Tags: android, android-workmanager

I enqueue files (chosen by the user) to upload and then update sync status with WorkManager like this:

```
fun schedule(files: List<String>) {
    var cont = workManager
                .beginUniqueWork(issueId, APPEND, files.map { workRequest(it) })
                .then(updateSyncStatusWork)
                .enqueue()
}
```

It works well. But when user choose a lot of files looking to logs I see that a lot of files are uploading at the same time (around 10 or even all of them). And quite a lot of timeouts happens. I believe that reducing a number of parallel uploads will decrease the number of timeouts but I can not find any API in WorkManager or WorkRequest that allows doing that.

PS I do not consider chaining them as failed upload will drop upload of all the files after it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The number of jobs that can run at the same time are actually determined by a thread pool that you configure. The default `Executor` is defined [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-1.0-dev/work/workmanager/src/main/java/androidx/work/Configuration.java#118).

Typically when you are using the `Worker` base class, you are associating an instance of the `Worker` to a thread on this `Executor`. If you want greater control on which thread your `Worker` is associated with, you might want to take a look at `CoroutineWorker` or `ListenableWorker`.

The number of threads in the default `Executor` are determined by the number  of cores on the device. If you want only `N` jobs to run at the same time you have to do the following:

- Disable the default `WorkManager` initializer (by disabling manifest merging for the content provider).
- Initialize `WorkManager` on `Application.onCreate()` or your own `ContentProvider`. You need to do this here because the OS can ask previously scheduled `Worker`s to run. For more information look at [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/WorkManager#initialize(android.content.Context,%20androidx.work.Configuration)).

```
val configuration = Configuration.Builder()
    // Defines a thread pool with 2 threads. 
    // This can be N (typically based on the number of cores on the device) 
    .setExecutor(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2))
    .build()

WorkManager.initialize(context, configuration)
```

In the above example I am creating a fixed size thread pool with 2 threads (which in turn can handle 2 `Workers` simultaneously). Now when you enqueue your `Worker`s you will see only 2 of them execute at the same time.

Comment: WorkManager configuration slightly modified after version 2.1.0, correct link - https://developer.android.com/guide/background/persistent/configuration/custom-configuration